# Como puedo poner una posición fija a un elemento en Parallax

Tags: jquery, css

Excelente día a todos, tengo el siguiente bloque de jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
  parallaxScroll();
});
function parallaxScroll(){
    var scrollEje_Y = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.clouds').css('right', + ((scrollEje_Y * 0.8)) + 'px');
    //$('.people-banner').css('right', + ((scrollEje_Y * -0.6)) + 'px');
    $('.info-banner').css('top', + ((scrollEje_Y * -0.5)) + 'px');
    $('.martin-sect').css('left: 14%', + ((scrollEje_Y * -0.5)) + 'px');

}
});
```

pero quiero que el elemento .martin-sect tenga un left del 14% de acuerdo al contenedor, esto lo declaro en el CSS y me da bien, pero es necesario que lo declare en el JS para poder hacer el efecto Parallax

Comment: No termina de quedar claro cuál es el problema (casi parece una pregunta con su propia respuesta. Deberías crear un [mcve] en el que se pueda ver el problema y añadir una descripción más detallada del problema.

Comment: Puedes agregar el `html` afectado para poder comprobar el funcionamiento. Lo que indica @alvaro-montoro es totalmente valido.